# writing actual jmeter listener data from jmeter plugin to a file

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I am using jmeter plugins for specific interpretation such as "Transactions per second".I tried to write the listener data using "write results to file" but it is writing raw sampler data in the file and the specific plugin related data that is getting plotted visually is missing.

Is there any way I can get this listener specific data into file?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any way to write the plot data directly to a file. What you can do is make a plot from the raw sampler data. Open the listener you're interested in and click on File "Browse...", then select your raw results file. The listener will display the results in the normal way.

http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/listeners.html